# Confirm box in CodeIgniter anchor link to delete record

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter

I am using the following code to delete a record from a database. But I am facing a problem: when I click on "cancel" in the confirm box then it deletes the record. If I click `cancel` it returns false but how does it delete the record?

What am doing wrong?

Javascript code:

```
function ConfirmDialog() {
  var x=confirm("Are you sure to delete record?")
  if (x) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

PHP code in view:

```
<?php
  echo anchor('user/deleteuser/'.$row->id, 'Delete', array('class'=>'delete', 'onclick'=>"return ConfirmDialog();"));
?>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try This:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="delete(<?php echo $row->id;?>);">Delete</a>
```

and use this in your script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var url="<?php echo base_url();?>";
    function delete(id){
       var r=confirm("Do you want to delete this?")
        if (r==true)
          window.location = url+"user/deleteuser/"+id;
        else
          return false;
        } 
</script>
```

Comment: @jamshidHashimi But how to delete record by form submit via post method? The above solution makes get request.

Answer (score 12):

Everything in one line

```
<?=anchor("user/deleteuser/".$row->id,"Delete",array('onclick' => "return confirm('Do you want delete this record')"))?>
```

Comment: This works for me but how about adding an icon instead of a "Delete" text?

Answer (score 5):

Are you getting any Javascript errors in the console? I suspect that some other Javascript may be interfering. This simple test page works fine:

```
<?php echo anchor('user/deleteuser/'.$row->id, 'Delete', array('class'=>'delete', 'onclick'=>"return confirmDialog();")); ?>

<script>
function confirmDialog() {
    return confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this record?")
}
</script>
```

Comment: Are you able to get a simple example like this to work? The rendered HTML should look like this: `<a href="user/deleteuser/123" onclick="return confirmDialog();">Delete</a>`

Answer (score 1):

In your **View**:

```
<?= anchor("admin/delete_article/{$article->id}", 'Test', ['name'=>'submit', 'value'=>'Delete', 'class'=>'btn btn-danger', 'onclick'=>'return confirm()']);
?>
```

**OR**

```
<?=
form_open('admin/delete_article'),
form_hidden('article_id', $article->id),
form_submit(['name'=>'submit', 'value'=>'Delete', 'class'=>'btn btn-danger', 'onclick'=>'return confirm()']),
form_close();
?>
```

JavaScript in your View:

```
<script>
function confirm(){
  job=confirm("Are you sure to delete permanently?");
if(job!=true){
  return false;
  }
}
</script>
```

See webGautam answer [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16891996/5737774)

Answer (score 0):

I use This in my code

```
<a href='<?php site_url('controler/function/$id');?>' onClick='javascript:return confirm(\"Are you sure to Delete?\")'>Delete</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="return isconfirm('<?php echo site_url('user/deleteuser/'.$row->id); ?>');">Delete</a>
```

Then your function will be like:

```
function isconfirm(url_val){
    alert(url_val);
    if(confirm('Are you sure you wanna delete this ?') == false)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        location.href=url_val;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?= 
      form_open('admin/delete_noti'),
      form_hidden('noti_id',$notification->id),
     form_submit('submit','Delete',array('onclick' => "return confirm('Do you want delete this record')",'class'=>'btn btn-danger float-center')),
      form_close();
    ?>
```

This is the deletion code. first of all we open form admin is our controller name and delete_noti is the function inside admin controller. We are sending id as hidden form. Here $notification is the variable which is passed through method which is available in controller.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, if you want javascript confirm: so when the user clicks, it asks to confirm and then goes to delete if the user clicks okay. You're asking confirmation when the row has already been deleted.

**In View Page :-**

```
<td><a href="<?php echo base_url().'user/deleteuser/'.$user['user_id'];?>" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure want to Delete this User?')">DELETE</a></td>
```

**Controller Code:-**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class user extends CI_Controller {

public function deleteuser($userid)
    {
      $this->db->delete('user', array('user_id'=>$userid)); 
      $this->session->set_flashdata('success','User deleted Successfully!!!');
            redirect(base_url().'admin/user');
    }
}
?>
```

**Then Show Success Message on View:-**

```
<div class="row col-md-12">
<?php 
   if($this->session->flashdata('success')){
 ?>
   <div class="alert alert-success "  style="display:none;"> 
     <?php  echo $this->session->flashdata('success'); ?>
<?php    
} else if($this->session->flashdata('error')){
?>
 <div class = "alert alert-danger"  style="display:none;">
   <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('error'); ?>
 </div>
<?php } ?>

</div></div>
```